# В Joomla 3 подключена Jquery, но не могу воспользоваться

Tags: jquery, joomla

Приветствую! При загрузки сайта на Joomla3 есть такая строчка (если смотреть исходный код, через браузер)

```
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

которая по сути подключает jQuery v1.11.3 , но скрипты которые я прописываю в шаблоне не работают.

Если я добавляю в шаблон

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

То скрипты работают. Я сверял 2 этих файла с гугла и из папки media они одинаковые.

В чем может быть причина?

РЕШЕНО
Там действительно есть 
jQuery.noConflict();

```
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Заменил в скрипте

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

на

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

Comment: Загружается ли первый файл? Загружается ли он до скриптов, которые вы прописываете в шаблоне? "Не работают" – есть ли в консоли ошибки?

Comment: Без описания ошибок в консоли браузера или ссылки на сайт гадать бесполезно.

Comment: В консоли это типа "инструменты разработчика" или firebug? Там ошибок нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что где-то вызывается `jQuery.noConflict()` или `jQuery.noConflict(true)`.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Верное предположение) потом идёт  получается ещё 4х библиотек. media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js + media/system/js/caption.js + modules/mod_vm_cart/assets/js/update_cart.js + /media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Пиши скрипты вот так и будет работать

```
(($)=>{
тут код
})(jQuery)
```

Так ещё можно

```
(($) => {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    alert('Hello world');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

http://codepen.io/korolariya/pen/jqjrLb

Вот так не пиши никогда

```
<script>
var test = 1;
</script>
```

Comment: Это я так понимаю в каком-то редакторе превратиться в jQuery(document).ready(function($) { тут код }  ?

Comment: нет это обычный код, стандартная обёртка области видимости